# How to Deploy On-Premises with Visual Studio Online Continuous Delivery

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

My team uses Visual Studio Online ("VSO") to manage our ALM.

We already have a push-button build-process in place to build code from our local Git repo (remotely) and deploy it to a Microsoft Azure Website on Azure.

In addition to this we want a local, development-testing environment built and deployed with a push of a button.

What is the best way to integrate an automated, on-premises development-testing deployment into our development pipeline from within VSO's ALM ecosystem?

[We do also own TFS 2012 -- is there a way to leverage it from VSO to drive an on-premises build deployment from our VSO git repo?]

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to your question? We're looking for something somewhat similar and I'm just curious what approach you ultimately took. Thanks

Comment: Hey Adam I've been manually deploying from within Visual Studio using the project's "PUBLISH" ability. I manually create a package that I then deploy with IIS to a development server. Painful.

Comment: Thank you. I've been doing some research for the last couple of days, but haven't gotten very far.  I will let you know if I find anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out this video from TechEd, it discusses the hybrid approach: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B363#fbid=

Comment: This question is a bit dated but just to chime in, you can install a TFS build agent on your local network and attach it to a Visual Studio Online account to act as your build controller. Your VSO builds can then kick off builds on your on-premises build agent and you can build/deploy locally as you like.

Comment: So, if you use VSO, automated deployment to anything other than Azure requires another local server?

Comment: @jDub VSO can deploy to Azure natively. If you want to deploy to one or more servers/clients in your local environment then, yes, you will need a local server to handle the deployments.

There are multiple ways to handle this but one of the simplest ways is to install a local TFS Build Server (with one or more build agents) and tie it to the VSO controller. You can also utilize other build platforms such as TeamCity or Jenkins that can build (and deploy) your artifacts based on VSO as well.

Answer (score 4):

To deploy builds on-premise, I installed an on-premise build server and used it as the default build controller in my build definition.

When installing the build server select your Visual Studio Online url to point the build server to your team project collection.

I used the instructions here
http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/

(normal issues when installing a build server remember to copy over your MSbuild folder from a machine with Visual Studio already installed etc...)

Comment: This seems like the joke  "How do I get to Dublin ... well if I was you sir, I wouldn't start from here". Is there anyway to get VSO (or should that be VSTS) to deploy to an on-premises IIS?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked, but this guy did it with an extension to be added to your VSTS account to deploy directly to an on-premise IIS. I'm going to check this solution today but I'm pretty sure it will work.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monub/2016/01/20/visual-studio-team-services-release-management-iis-web-deployment-vnext/

**UPDATE**

Better yet, MSDN released a complete doc for deploying an asp.net app on IIS

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-vm